# Laravel 5.3 send email reminder to multiple users in queue

Tags: php, laravel, email, queue

I need to send reminder emails to users in queue

Currently I have

UserController.php

```
public function postSendUsersPaymentRequest(Request $request){
    $users_ids     = $request->get('user_checked');        
    dispatch(new SendPaymentRequestEmail($users_ids)); 
    return response()->json(['code' => 200], 200);
}
```

\App\Jobs\SendPaymentRequestEmail.php

```
public function handle(UserRepository $userRepo)
{
    $users =   $userRepo->getUserInfoDetails(3,1,1)->whereIn('user_id',$this->users_ids);
    foreach($users as $user){
        $this->emailPaymentRequest($user);
    }
}

private function emailPaymentRequest($user){
    Mail::queue($this->email_vew, ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {             
        $from         = Config::get('mail.from');
        $project_name = Config::get('app.project_name');                         
        $m->from('fromemail', $project_name);
        $m->to('toemail', $user->name)->subject('Payment Request');                                                    
    });       
}
```

But email is sending without queuing.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What is `QUEUE_DRIVER` in your `.env` file? Also, what is the name of your `queue` in `config/queue.php`?

Comment: make your queue driver to database and migrate database with queue's jobs table. if driver is sync then it will send mail directly without waiting.

Comment: Yes, I solved. QUEUE_DRIVER was file in .env but I used database as driver.

Answer (score 0):

Add `QUEUE_DRIVER=database` into your *.env* file.